# How to prove the equal probabilities for the last digits (1, 3, 7, 9) of prime numbers?

Tags: probability, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers

According to the comment to this question:

[What are the probabilities for the last digits of prime numbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2163638/what-are-the-probabilities-for-the-last-digits-of-prime-numbers)

by [Dirichlet's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions) the probability for each of final digits (1, 3, 7, 9) is $\frac{1}{\varphi(10)}$ = $\frac{1}{4}$.

What is this theorem called? How can one prove this theorem? If there is existing reference or paper to show the proof of this theorem, that would also be appreciated.

EDIT & UPDATE:

Based on all the comments so far, I have the impression that, the existence of probabilities for the prime numbers with each one of final digits 1, 3, 7, 9 can neither be rigorously proved, nor be disproved. So I have a straight questions instead. Is the existence of these probabilities still an open question? A clear answer to the question would be preferred. Of course, any further detailed discussion and elaboration would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Dirichlet theorem. The proof is not easy.

Comment: This is a very deep result. In fact, numerically it does not seem to be the case (see Chebycheff-bias) , but in fact in the long run all residues have the same expected frequency.

Comment: A detailed proof is in Apostol's  _Introduction to Analytic Number Theory_.

Comment: Yep, @B.Goddard, I have it :)

Comment: I think this goes far beyond Dirichlet's theorem. He only proved that infinite many of each residue occur.

Comment: Dirichlet theorem also specifies the frequency, Asyntotically, every digit must occur at the same rate.

Comment: Dirichlet computed the analytic densities (sometimes also called the [Dirichlet density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_density#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20Dirichlet%20density,use%20than%20the%20natural%20density.), because of this and related results) here...which is probably not exactly what the OP has in mind for probability.  Natural density fits intuition better...and the same result holds for that density, but that's not part of what Dirichlet proved.

Comment: It's a general result that, if the natural density exists, so does the Dirichlet density and the two coincide, but it's possible for the Dirichlet density to exist while the natural density does not.  So...Dirichlet's proof does imply that, if the probabilities exist (in the usual sense) then they must be equal, but it's not quite enough to prove existence.

Comment: There is no way to uniformly choose a random prime, so we can only talk about the density: if we pick a random prime from $1$ to $N,$ what take the probabilities for the last digits. What   are the limits of these probabilities as $N\to\infty?$ These limits are not, in and of themselves, probabilities.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Could you, or anyone else, please elaborate the statement that the limit (as $N \rightarrow \infty$) of the probabilities for the last digits of randomly chosen primes (from $1$ to $N$) don't exist? Thanks!

Comment: I didn't say it doesn't exist, I the limits are not probabilities.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews My apologies that I'm a bit lost with the statement in your previous comment, "What are the limits of these probabilities as N→∞". Do you mean the "limits of these frequencies"? If so, e.g., the frequency is defined by the count of primes ending with one of digits 1, 3,7, 9 divided by the total count of primes (< N). Could you please also explain the statement that, the limits (as N→∞) of these frequencies "are not, in and of themselves, probabilities"?

Comment: That might be more than you can handle. You can't pick a random prime with each prime equally likely. We can for finite sets, but not countably infinite sets. So we can't say "If we pick a random prime,  the probability that it ends in $1$ is $1/4.$" There is no such way to pick a random prime. You can pick a random prime $\leq N.$ So you can't say the limit is a probability, only that the limit exists and is $1/4.$ I probably can't go into details about what a probability is, in a comment - you'll have to cover the topic somewhere else in any basic college probability class.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks for your patience with my ignorance of pure math, not mentioning the analytical number theory. Now I see, there is no proof of the existence of probability for a random prime that has the last digit one of 1, 3, 7, 9. To be more specific, it seems from your answer that, the condition of the large number theorem, namely i.i.d. sampling sequence, is not met. If I misunderstood the point, or anyone else would like to elaborate more this point and related, please do help. Again, thanks for your reply.

Comment: This is a special case of Chebotaryov's density theorem.

Comment: By the way, to not confuse any future readers of this discussion, @ThomasAndrews's statement, in his last comment, "You can't pick a random prime with each prime equally likely" seems purely wrong. It should be stated as, one can't randomly pick a prime with each independently and identically distributed (iid). The iid is definitely different than the "equally likely". Hopefully I'm not misunderstanding anything here and this clarifies the basic concept in probability theory.

Comment: The difficulty you are having, fin, has nothing to do with primes. The same difficulty comes up with the question, what is the probability that an integer is even? You want to say that the probability is one-half, but the trouble with that is it's predicated on a probability distribution on the integers where each integer has the same probability, and there's no such thing on the integers (nor on any countably infinite set). All we can say is that the limit as $n\to\infty$ of the probability that an integer between $1$ and $n$ is even, is one-half.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks for the clarification. I suppose it should be good enough to say, the limit as n→∞ of the probability that a prime, between $1$ and $n$, that modulo 10 is 1, 3, 7, or 9 , is one-fourth.

Comment: That sums up Greg Martin's answer, fin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The theorem that is closest in spirit to the "probabilities" the OP describes is the [prime number theorem for arithmetic progressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Prime_number_theorem_for_arithmetic_progressions), which has indeed been proved rigorously for any fixed modulus such as $10$. Even though they are not technically probabilities, they are limits of probabilities and number theorists become comfortable referring to them as probabilities without straying into invalid mathematics.